# Не работает вызов свойства

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня объект и я (для создания одной функции) хотел посмотреть можно ли "вызвать" свойства. Нашел соответствующий код, два свойства работают (itemName и inputId), а остальные (itemId и itemParentId) нет. То есть у "работающих" свойств высвечивается `alert` с сообщением и текстом, а у "не работающих" тоже высвечивается `alert`, но абсолютно пустой. В консоли никаких ошибок не было. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: 1,
      inputId: 'n_' + 2
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1,
      inputId: 'n_' + 3
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 4
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'n_' + 6
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'n_' + 7
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'n_' + 8
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 9
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 10
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 10,
      inputId: 'n_' + 11
    }

  ]
};

function showProps(obj, objName) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result += objName + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }
  }
  alert(result);
}

showProps(listCategories.data[0].itemId, "listCategories.data[0].itemId");//это не работает
showProps(listCategories.data[0].itemName, "listCategories.data[0].itemName");//это работает
showProps(listCategories.data[0].itemParentId, "listCategories.data[0].itemParentId");//это не работает
showProps(listCategories.data[0].inputId, "listCategories.data[0].inputId");//это работает
```

Comment: Простите, а какие **собственные** свойства у объекта `Number` вы хотите выводить? Вы вообще понимаете, что делает функция `showProps`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Да вроде более менее понимаю... И кажется ваш комментарий помог мне разобраться в проблеме, благодарю :"D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [
    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'n_' + 1
    },
    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: 1,
      inputId: 'n_' + 2
    }
  ]
}, l = listCategories.data.length

while (l--) {
  showProps(listCategories.data[l])
};

function showProps(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(obj[i]);
    }
  }
}
```